# How I run my react-native project(Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up:

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, mobile

I trying to run my react-native anroid project. I use android 12 (S). And sdk verison 31.0.0. But i cant run my project.

My error :

```
PS C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje> npm run android

> BosBirProje@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Launching emulator...
info Successfully launched emulator.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\b
in.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masa�st�\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modu
les.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\BosBirP
roje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loade
r:995:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (
node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  require
Stack: []}Node.js v18.12.1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/do
cs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\b
in.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masa�st�\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modu
les.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\BosBirP
roje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loade
r:995:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (
node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  require
Stack: []}Node.js v18.12.1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\b
uild\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

I trying to react-native doctor and my react-native doctor output:

```
PS C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje> npx @react-native-community/cli doctor
Common
 ✓ Node.js
 ✓ npm

Android
 ✓ JDK
 ✓ Android Studio - Required for building and installing your app on Android
 ✖ Android SDK - Required for building and installing your app on Android
   - Versions found: N/A
   - Version supported: 31.0.0
 ✓ ANDROID_HOME

Errors:   1
Warnings: 0

Attempting to fix 1 issue...

Android
 ✔ Android SDK configured. You might need to restart your PC for all changes to take effect.
```

I reboot my pc as suggested and do npm run android. And my new output:

```
PS C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje> npm run android

> BosBirProje@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\b
in.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masa�st�\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modu
les.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\BosBirP
roje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loade
r:995:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (
node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  require
Stack: []}Node.js v18.12.1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 6s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/do
cs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
:ReactNative:Unexpected empty result of running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli\build\bin.js, config]' command.
:ReactNative:Running '[node, C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\b
in.js, config]' command failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masa�st�\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modu
les.gradle' line: 413

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:998  throw err;  ^Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\MasaÃ¼stÃ¼\BosBirP
roje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\bin.js'    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loade
r:995:15)    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (
node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',  require
Stack: []}Node.js v18.12.1

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 6s

    at makeError (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-n
ative-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Masaüstü\BosBirProje\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\b
uild\index.js:108:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

1-) Finally I added the `local.properties` file to this location "C:\Users\omer2\OneDrive\Desktop\BosBirProject\android".
2-) I added the following commands in the `gradle.properties` file:

```
newArchEnabled=false
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

3-) I updated and reinstalled all npm packages

4-) I also tried to :

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-cli

npm install -g react-native-cli

npm install -g react-native
```

5-) I can't run the project even though I did all these, what would you recommend to me?